# Is it possible to redirectsTo a dynamic segment through Ember.Route?

Tags: routes, ember.js

I want a certain route to immediately redirect to /50

```
index: Ember.Route.extend({
  route: '/',
  redirectsTo: '/50',
}),
post: Ember.Route.extend({
  route: '/:post_id',
  connectOutlets: function(router) {
  },
  deserialize: function() {
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `redirectsTo` basically is just 'translated' to the call `router.transitionTo(redirection)` inside `connectOutlets` (see [routable.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/1ebfd08e1260f238808ecaf37faa3f42ca1dbcf6/packages/ember-routing/lib/routable.js#L34-40)), you can solve your issue in a similar way, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/DLYQK/:

```js
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    enableLogging: true,
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
                router.route('/50');
            }
        }),
        post: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/:post_id'
        })
    })
});

App.initialize();
```

Comment: Trying to figure out how to do this with the new Router magics.

Comment: It can be done using a combination of `serialize` and `model`. Docs: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize